# JavaScript Callback Confusing Behavior

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, callback, arrow-functions

Having trouble writing a callback function in JavaScript that returns a mapped array with each number in it incremented by one.

```js
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

    const each = (elements, cb) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        cb(elements[i], i);
      }
    };
    
    const map = (elements, cb) => {
      const mappedArr = [];
      each(elements, item => {
        mappedArr.push(cb(item));
      });
      return mappedArr;
    };



    const cb = (e) => {
      e += 1;
    }


    const newArr = map(arr, cb);
    console.log(newArr) // [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]
```

Your patience is appreciated in advance; I'm still learning and trying to understand callbacks. Please help me understand what I did wrong here.

Comment: cb function isn't returning anything - i.e. that's equivalent to having `return undefined` - perhaps you wanted `const cb = (e) => e + 1;` (implied return) or `const cb = (e) => {
  return e + 1;
}`

Comment: @SeanValdiva: Other than the other answers, you can condense down to `const cb = e => e++;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `cb` is not returning anything at the moment, so the return value defaults to `undefined`. Use an arrow function with implicit return (no `{` `}`s) instead, so that the incremented value is returned.

Also, try to avoid implicitly creating global variables (with your `arr`):

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

const each = (elements, cb) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    cb(elements[i], i);
  }
};

const map = (elements, cb) => {
  const mappedArr = [];
  each(elements, item => {
    mappedArr.push(cb(item));
  });
  return mappedArr;
};

const cb = e => e + 1;

const newArr = map(arr, cb);
console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 2):

return in missing in `cb` function.Check this:

```js
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

const each = (elements, cb) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    cb(elements[i], i);
  }
};

const map = (elements, cb) => {
  const mappedArr = [];
  each(elements, item => {
    mappedArr.push(cb(item));
  });
  return mappedArr;
};



const cb = (e) => {
  return e += 1;
}


const newArr = map(arr, cb);
console.log(newArr) // [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]
```